# Please Define this FHA Loan Requirement

Tags: united-states, mortgage

While looking up FHA loan requirements, I found the following line interesting:

> Must have a steady employment history or worked for the same employer for the past two years.

From: http://www.zillow.com/mortgage-learning/fha-loan/#requirements

I've been a tech contractor for most of my career, which means while I've never been unemployed for more than a couple months at most, I've also never stayed in a single position for more than a year, and usually it's closer to six months.

What constitutes "steady employment history?"

Comment: Generally a minimum of 2 years

Comment: @stevenackley Does that mean I probably wouldn't qualify since I jump around a lot?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's up to the underwriter. If you have decent credit and reasonable income, you shouldn't have a huge issue. You'd probably be better off with a conventional mortgage IMO

Comment: See here http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/fha-loan-less-than-2-years-employment-history?rq=1

Comment: @stevenackley While I'd love to get a conventional mortgage, at 20% down, closing costs, and six months of income in savings just in case, I'd have to save up a little over $100k, and there's no way I can pull that off.

Comment: You don't need 20% down. You can do as low as 5% and pick up the PMI

Comment: @stevenackley Really? I thought anything under 20% down was automatically an FHA loan. To the research!

Comment: You'll still have PMI payments until you have reached the 20% amount, but you'll get a lower interest rate which will benefit you in the long run

Comment: @stevenackley FWIW, my credit rating is 620 due to some sizable medical collections against me. So, that's another reason I probably don't qualify for a conventional loan.

Comment: You can get manual underwriting which may still be able to get you into a conventional regardless of your score. Try churchill mortgage or someone like them and see what they say

Comment: When you say "tech contractor" do you mean that you're self-employed (e.g. getting Form 1099 from "clients" instead of form W-2 from an "employer" and filing Schedule C on your tax returns)?

Comment: @Brick, it's a W2. How is a W2 a contractor? I hear you say... It's complicated and depressing.

Comment: Your employer is the company that sends you the W2.  You've been with them for the last several years, right?  Do they lay you off between engagements or pay you while you're on the bench?

Answer (score 1):

In the FHA process, there are a few things you will be asked for:

- Pay stubs
- W2 statements
- Bank statements
- Tax returns

As a W2 contractor, assuming you categorize this under the guidelines for seasonal employment, here are the criteria:

> Has worked the same line of work for the past two years; and
>
> Is reasonably likely to be rehired for the next season.
>
> For employees with Seasonal Employment income, the Mortgagee must average the income earned over the previous two full years to calculate Effective Income.

As opposed to self-employment:

> A Mortgagee may consider income as stable after a 20 percent reduction if the Mortgagee can:
>
> Document the reduction in income was the result of an extenuating circumstance;
>
> The Borrower can demonstrate the income has been stable or increasing for a minimum of 12 months; and
>
> The Borrower qualifies utilizing the reduced income.

In general,

> Effective Income must:
>
> Be likely to continue through at least the first three years of the
>   mortgage;
>
> Be documentable;
>
> Be legally derived; and
>
> Be reported to the IRS when required

**References**

- [Single Family Housing Policy Handbook 4000.1 - Title II Insured Housing Program Forward Mortgages Origination through Post-Closing/Endorsement: Manual Underwriting of the Borrower](https://www.hud.gov/sites/documents/FY16_SFHB_MOD4_UNDER.PDF)
- [FHA Loan Income Questions: Pay Stubs and W-2s](https://www.fhanewsblog.com/2016/01/fha-loan-income-questions-pay-stubs-and-w-2s/)